# Quartic Formula existance

Tags: polynomials, quartics

There is a formula for cubic equations and quadratic equations. Is there a formula for the equations in the form $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+f=0$ I also skipped $e$ because of Euler's constant.

Comment: It takes all of 2 seconds to [google it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version:

Let the biquadratic be $$a_0 x^4 +4a_1 x^3 +6a_2 x^2 +4a_3 x + a_4=0$$
and the two invariants are

$$g_2=a_0 a_4 -4 a_1 a_3 +3 a_2^2$$
$$g_3=a_0 a_2 a_4 -a_0 a_3^2 -a_1^2 a_4  +2 a_1a_2 a_3 -a_2^3.$$
Then the resolvent cubic is
$$4z^3 -g_2 z -g_3=0$$

with roots

$$u_0=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 +\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 -\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}$$
$$u_1= \frac{\zeta^2}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 +\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}+\frac{\zeta}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 -\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}$$
$$u_2=\frac{\zeta}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 +\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}+\frac{\zeta^2}{2}\sqrt[3]{g_3 -\sqrt{g_3^2 +\left(\frac{g_2}{3}\right)^3}}$$

And the roots of the biquadratic are given by

$$r_0=-\frac{1}{a_0} \left[a_1 + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_0 } + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_1 } + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_2 }\right]$$
$$r_1=-\frac{1}{a_0}\left[a_1 + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_0 } - \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_1 } - \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_2 }\right]$$
$$r_2=-\frac{1}{a_0}\left[a_1 - \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_0 } - \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_1 } + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_2 }\right]$$
$$r_3=-\frac{1}{a_0}\left[a_1 -\sqrt{a_1^2  -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_0 } + \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_1 } - \sqrt{a_1^2 -a_0a _2  -a_0 u_2 }\right]$$

Comment: what is ζ in $u0$, $u1$, and $u2$?